# Update values anytime row is selected mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a row with an article. I'd like to update `views` column anytime article is viewed - this means anytime the row is affected by `SELECT` command. Is that posible in mysql?
I've found an [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) about auto updatig on `UPDATE`, but that's not what I want.

Comment: No, it isn't. There is no event being emitted when `SELECT` is performed. You have to control it on your application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had answered in another question, this is only possible if you have a trigger on the select command, which is actually, impossible.

The closest you can get is to complicate things a little.  You need to first close this table access to users.  Then have a stored procedure given access, any "select" to this table should be possible only through this stored procedure, then you can update the table inside the same stored procedure

Comment: Or, you decide you won't complicate things at all and you drop the silly idea of emulating a SELECT. Then you realize that you have some sort of an app that performs those selects and things become crystal clear all of a sudden.

Comment: I like the comment, and agree 100%  but since he seems to be around for some time in SO, I thought he may have already some constraints which does not allow him to touch the APP

Comment: No, I have no constraints and I will, much likely, just modify the appropriate class to perform updates automatically when values are being recovered. I asked the question anyway, because I was curious whether it is possible - and failed to find any answer.